# Difference between times entered as text

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

i am new to c# and i have been trying to create a code that  shows the total number of hours worked..eg a person working from 8am to 4pm means he works 8 hrs a day.
i want a code that shows how many hours he worked.

i tried for loop but i am not getting it right..
please help me out

```
int from = Convert.ToInt32(frA.Text);
int to = Convert.ToInt32(toA.Text);

for (from = 0; from <= to; from++)
{
    totalA.Text = from.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the contents of the two textboxes?

Comment: You don't need loop to calculate that. You need to consider the time format, in your case 4pm => 16 hour in 24 hour format. So basically all you need to do is: WorkingDuration = 16 - 8; totalA.Text = WorkingDuration.ToString();

Comment: thanks..i got your logic..but in my form i want to let the user enter the time...so he can even enter 9-5 or 8-8 or any random number..how shud i solve tht ?

Comment: Instead of textboxes I would suggest using 2 datetimepickers, which can be configured to show just time.  The values from them can be used to give value to a timespan variable.

Answer (score 6):

A loop isn't what you need here.  You could use `DateTime` and a `Timespan`:

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 07, 04, 08,00, 00);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 07, 04, 16,00, 00);

    TimeSpan ts = end - start;

    Console.Write(ts.Hours);
```

Here I create two `DateTime` objects for today (04/07/2013).  One has the start time of `08:00` and the end time `16:00` (4pm).

The Timespan object `ts` subtracts these dates, you can then use the `.Hours` property.

Comment: my form is user generated..its nt  only frm 8-4..he can enter any random time..even 9-6 or anything like tht

Comment: @user2549530 - you can replace 08 and 16 with them integers from your application and then pass them to the DateTime constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to convert the string to `int`, then you can initialize a `TimeSpan` struct:

```
int from, to;
if (int.TryParse(frA.Text, out from) && int.TryParse(toA.Text, out to))
{
    if (to <= from)
        MessageBox.Show("To must be greater than From.");
    else
    {
        TimeSpan workingHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(to - from);
        // now you have the timespan
        int hours = workingHours.Hours;
        double minutes = workingHours.TotalMinutes;
        // ...
    }
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid hours.");
```

You don't really need the `TimeSpan` here, you could also use the `int` alone. Used it anyway to show that it allows to provide other properties like minutes or second.

Answer (score 0):

If that inputs can be taken to DateTime, then you can do it like the following line of code

```
          double totalHours = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now).TotalHours;
```